# How to call a function from the bottom of a function that placed on top inside controller using AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

I can't call a function from bottom to that calling function placed top of the called function. Is it possible or any other way to do it?

Thanks Advance..
Example:

```
$scope.function1();                 //it's working fine
$scope.function1=function(){
}
$scope.function2=function(){
}

$scope.function3=function(){
$http.post()..some ajax response{
$scope.function1();             //i can't call function1 from here..
}
}
```

Comment: Could you post all your code, with controllers, etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is due to the fact that `$scope` in Angular is a local scope relative to the current controller or directive. So, one `$scope` cannot access another $scope. But you could use `$rootScope`, which is relative to your Angular application, in order to access a `$rootScope.function` from any controller.

See the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what you are trying to do. If you want to use the ajax response data of function3 in function1. you can do like this-

```
$scope.function3 = function(callback) {
$http.post...... success : function(response){

callback(response);
}

}

$scope.function3(function(res){
  $scope.function1(res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would try the following [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/W38PiFxr5HBvz9wmIZ0U?p=preview)

```
testApp.controller('Test', ["$scope", "$http",
  function($scope, $http){

    $scope.setText = function(text){
      $scope.hello = text;
    }

    $scope.setText("Loading...");

    $scope.request = function(){
      $http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk").
      success(function(data){
        $scope.setText(data.weather[0].main)
      });
    }
    $scope.request();
  }
]);
```